# saving array of UIImage to parse as one file

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In my swift app I have an array of UIImage and I need to save it to parse in one row and one column(as one file). I can do it when it's one image by using PFFile with no problem but for UIImage Array it doesn't work. How can I do It ? Is it Possible ? if it's possible how can I retrieve it from parse ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save an array of NSData()

> images: [NSData()]
>   UIImageView.image = UIImage(data: images[0])